# Values in an inductively defined sequence of sets

Tags: combinatorics, logic, propositional-calculus

Consider the following sequence of sets:

\begin{align}
T_0 &= \{(0,0)\} \\
T_{n+1} &= \{(1+x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2):(x_1,y_1)\in T_n, (x_2,y_2)\in T_k \text{ for some } k\leq n\} \\
 &\quad \cup \{(x_1,1+y_1):(x_1,y_1)\in T_n\}.
\end{align}

What values of $(a,b)$ are in $T_n$ for a given $n$?

For reference, here are the first couple values of $T_n$:

$T_1 = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$

$T_2 = \{(1,2),(2,0),(3,0),(1,1),(2,1),(0,2)\}$

$T_3$ is pretty big.

So far, I have that the first coordinate can take any value from $n$ to $2^n-1$, but I am having trouble finding a systematic way of describing corresponding possible values for the second coordinate.

If it helps, this question is derived from trying to determine the possible lengths of a propositional formula of height $n$.

Comment: There is a minor typo, for $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)=(0,1) \in T_1$ the first rule gives $(1,2) \in T_2$. As a side remark, it might be useful to state the full original problem that you actually want to solve, rather than the part where you get stuck in your chosen path towards a solution, because your approach need not be the easiest strategy for solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, it is probably better to ask the actual problem you wanted to solve. The current question has a rather messy and lengthy solution and might not be too useful. For that reason I only give here the main results and the main steps required in a proof.

The set of points $T_n$ is a convex set of lattice points $(x,y)$ in the 2D plane. It is relatively easy to show that $0 \leq x \leq 2^n-1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 2^{n-1}$. For the actual boundaries of the set, you will find that the set is bounded from below by two lines $x+y \geq n$ and $y \geq 0$. The upper limit is more complicated and consists of inequalities, the number of which increases with the value of $n$. One can show that for given $n$ and $x \in [0,2^n-1]$ that all points are found by
$$
\max (n-x,0) \leq y \leq 2^{k+1} + (n-k-2)(x+1) \qquad \qquad \qquad (*)
$$
where $k$ is an integer dependent on $x$ and given by
$$
2^k \leq x + 1 < 2^{k+1}.
$$

[image]

For proving this result a number of steps are required.

1) The range of $x$ and $y$. From the transformation it is immediately clear that $x,y \geq 0$. With the help of induction you can prove that the domain is restricted by $T_n \subset [0,2^n-1] \times [0,2^{n-1}]$ for $n\geq1$ using the maximum growth possible in either direction.

2) With induction you can also show that 
$$
(x,0) \in T_n \qquad\text{for}\qquad n\leq x\leq2^n-1
$$
$$
(x,n-x)\in T_n \qquad\text{for}\qquad 0 \leq x \leq n
$$
You can also use this to show that $x+y\geq n$ which establishes the lower bounds in $(*)$

3) If you would represent the sets graphically and consider the transformation for low values of $n$, it will be clear that the set $T_n$ is convex and that the boundary is a polygon.

4) The vertices of the polygon-boundary of $T_n$ are given by $(2^k-1,[n-k]2^k)$ for $0\leq k \leq n$. Note that each vertex under the first transformation rule maps on to the boundary of $T_{n+1}$, i.e., $(x,y) \rightarrow (2x+1,2y)$ gives that $(2^k-1,[n-k]2^k) \rightarrow (2^{k+1}-1,[(n+1)-(k+1)]2^{k+1})$ complemented with applying the second transformation on $(0,n) \rightarrow (0,n+1)$. The only other vertex to be added to make the boundary complete is the point $(n,0)$.

5) The rest of the boundary are straight lines connecting the vertices, giving rise to the upper limit in $(*)$.

A full prove along these lines is possible but quite a bit of writing.

The derivation can be simplified and made more intuitive, if we consider the sets $S_n=\cup_{i=0}^n T_n$. With the innitial condition $T_0=\{(0,0)\}$, we then find that
\begin{eqnarray}
S_{n+1}
 & = & \left[ \bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1} T_n \right] \cup T_0\\
 & = & \left[ \bigcup_{k=0}^{n} \{p+q+(1,0)|p \in T_{k}; q \in T_i \text{ with } 0 \leq i \leq k\} \cup \{p+(0,1)|p\in T_{k}\} \right] \cup T_0\\
 & = & \left[ \bigcup_{k=0}^{n} \{p+q+(1,0)|p \in T_{k}; q \in S_k\} \right] \cup \left[ \bigcup_{k=0}^{n} \{p+(0,1)|p\in T_{k}\} \right] \cup S_0\\
 & = & \{p+q+(1,0)|p,q \in S_n\} \cup \{p+(0,1)|p\in S_{n}\} \cup S_0
\end{eqnarray}

Effectively, this means that $S_n$ is obtained by adding the grid-points $(x,y)$ in the triange $x,y\geq$ and $x+y<n$ to $T_n$.

By considering $q=(0,1)$ in the first set, it is obvious that almost all points generated by the second set in the prescription for $S_{n+1}$ are already included by the first set. The only exception are the points $(0,y)$ with $1 \leq y \leq n+1$. Including the point $(0,0)$, we can therefore summarize the sets $S_n$ by
\begin{eqnarray}
S_0 & = & \{(0,0)\} \\
S_{n+1} & = & \{p+q+(1,0)|p,q \in S_n\} \cup \{(0,k) |0 \leq k \leq n+1 \}
\end{eqnarray}

[image]

We now apply a particular translation of the points in each set $S_n$, that will depend explicitly on $n$. This does of course not affect their number or the shape of the set in a graphical representation, and obtain the sets $R_n$
$$
R_n = \{p-(2^{n-2}-1,0) | p \in S_n\}
$$
This results in $R_0=\{(\frac{3}{4},0)\}$ and $R_1=\{(\frac{1}{2},0),(\frac{1}{2},1),(\frac{3}{2},0)\}$, but for $n \geq 2$ the set $R_n$ will only contain integer grid-points.

Applying this translation to the transformation for $T_n$, we find that this results in
\begin{eqnarray}
R_0 & = & \{(\frac{3}{4},0)\} \\
R_{n+1} & = & \{p+q|p,q \in R_n\} \cup \{(1-2^{n-1},k) |0 \leq k \leq n+1 \}
\end{eqnarray}

[image]

This means that in each iteration the domain is mainly scaled by a factor 2 in both $x$ and $y$ direction with respect to the origin (this is the reason for the particular choice or translation) and a single vertical line of points is added on the extreme left side. With this in mind, it is then easy to check and prove by induction that for $n \geq 2$, the set $R_n$ contains all integer grid-points that are bounded by the inequalities $y \geq 0$, $x \geq 1-2^{n-2}$, and $ y \leq (k-1) (x+2^{n-2}) + 2^{k+1}$ for $0 \leq k < n$, as well as that the corresponding vertices of the polygon are given by $\{(2^{n-k}-2^{n-2}, k 2^{n-k})| 0 \leq k \leq n\} \cup \{(1-2^{n-2},0)\}$.

Transforming this result back to the set $S_n$ and $T_n$ gives the results as mentioned above.